# Has my battery actually been replaced? Samsung A40

Tags: battery, battery-history

I went to a phone repair shop to have my display replaced, which was cracked. I took the opportunity to have the battery replaced too: My Samsung A40 is four years old and I noticed that the battery wasn't lasting as long as it used to. I have picked up my phone from the shop and while it is obvious that the display has been replaced, I am suspicious that they simply left the old battery in there:

1. The battery is draining quickly, as it was before: It's gone from 97% to 90% in about two hours. (I have not charged it since getting it back.)
2. When I turned on my phone after getting it back from the shop, the battery was at 97%, which is, I think, more or less the level it was at before I switched it off in the shop.
3. Under Settings > Device care > Battery > Battery usage, there is usage data for the last seven days. Shouldn't this be blank? Or does a change of batter *not* reset this?

Am I just being overly suspicious or is there a way to confirm whether the battery has been replaced? (Even if I did open it up and look, I didn't think to write down the serial number of the old battery.) If I were to go back to the shop to complain, then I would need firm proof.

EDIT: My original question was not clear. Put succinctly: **Is there a way to tell whether a battery has been replaced using only the software?**

Comment: How should the device know the battery has been replaced? A battery is a built-in component not designed to be replaced regularly. Even the maximum battery mAh is hard-coded into the ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping 7% in 2 hours is not excessive.  You can see under battery usage, what is using it up.  The biggest user is normally the touch screen.  On some phones the GPS consumes a fair bit of power.  Switch it off, if you dont need it on all the time.

> **Battery life**
> Battery life is definitely not one of the strongest suits of the Galaxy A40 but it's not necessarily a weak point either. The 3,100mAh unit didn't deliver the runtimes we expected, especially in the web browsing and video playback tests. Still, an overall 73h endurance rating is fairly dependable so you will **probably squeeze out a full day of moderate usage**.

From [gsmarena](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a40-review-1924p3.php).  Note I have no affiliation with the site, its just the first one in the search.